# Twitter Search API, get profile url of the search string

Tags: twitter

In the response of a search query, there is something with the key "source". Is that the profile url of the member ? If not, how do I get the Twitter profile url of a result (from the response of a search query) ?

See the "source" key in a typical respone :

```
   "profile_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1130541908/funcheap_icon_twitter_normal.gif",
   "source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http://dlvr.it&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;dlvr.it&lt;/a&gt;",
   "text":"10/8/11: Blue Angels Wine Tasting | Treasure Island http://t.co/fyL8Rs5f",
```

Answer (score 1):

The `source` key is a link to the Twitter client which sends the tweet. Examples : web (web interface), Tweetian, Seesmic, Hotot, Echofon, Tweetbot, Plume, TweetDeck, dlvr.it (in your example), MetroTwit...

For the profile URL, jou just have to add the user's screen name at the Twitter URL. For example : https://twitter.com/firefox for the @firefox Twitter user.